# Why MTLDevice.NewCommandQueue return null?

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal, metalkit

On iOS (on an 64 bit app) it's work perfectly, however on MACOS (on a 32 bit app), `MTLDevice.NewCommandQueue` return always null? any idea why?

Comment: What Mac hardware and what version of macOS?

Comment: @warrenm I m on a virtual machine, does it matter? it's macos 10.14

Comment: Is the `MTLDevice` itself not null?

Comment: @Itai : no, MTLDevice is not null just MTLDevice.NewCommandQueue return null :(

Comment: What’s the value of the `MTLDevice`’s name property? I’m curious what your virtualization layer is reporting as far as GPU “hardware”

Comment: @warrenm : MTLDevice's name is empty

Comment: It sounds like the virtualization layer provides a device that Metal doesn't quite know how to deal with...